# How can I get the values new.TITLE['kinds.of'].food

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to regex. I have this string

`new.TITLE['kinds.of'].food`

or

`new.TITLE['deep thought'].food`

I want to retrieve these tokens:

```
new, TITLE, kinds.of, food.
```

or (2nd example)

```
new, TITLE, deep thought, food.
```

I can't simply **split** it with `'.'`  I need **regex** match to get the values.
How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with *tokens* a *parser* (**FST** - *Finite State Machine* in this case) should do:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ParseIt(string value) {
  int lastIndex = 0;

  bool inApostroph = false;

  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i) {
    char ch = value[i];

    if (ch == '\'') {
      inApostroph = !inApostroph;

      continue;
    }

    if (inApostroph)
      continue;

    if (ch == '.' || ch == ']' || ch == '[') {
      if (i - lastIndex > 0) {
        if (value[lastIndex] != '\'')
          yield return value.Substring(lastIndex, i - lastIndex);
        else {
          string result = value.Substring(lastIndex, i - lastIndex).Replace("''", "'");

          yield return result.Substring(1, result.Length - 2);
        }
      }

      lastIndex = i + 1;
    }
  }

  if (lastIndex < value.Length)
    yield return value.Substring(lastIndex);
}
```

Tests:

```
string test1 = @"new.TITLE['kinds.of'].food";
string test2 = @"new.TITLE['deep thought'].food";

string[] result1 = ParseIt(test1).ToArray(); 
string[] result2 = ParseIt(test2).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result1));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result2));
```

Outcome:

```
new
TITLE
kinds.of
food

new
TITLE
deep thought
food
```